# Amazon S3 - Get destination version id after copying object (.NET)

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I'm storing files on S3 while maintaining a table on my local DB for (mutable) metadata associated with the version, so I need the version ID when performing file operations.

When I add a new file using the .NET AWSSDK, no problem, since the PutObjectResponse has a VersionId, but when I copy a file, the CopyObjectResponse only has the SourceVersionId (both in practice, and according to the [SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TS3CopyObjectResponse_NET4_5.html)).

```
{  
   "ETag":"\"6b841006ec17a5ce8c41db87639811e8\"",
   "LastModified":"2014-07-25T07:43:15.000Z",
   "Expiration":null,
   "SourceVersionId":"9WeyyOE_rBiMVrra_jY1JpxLgtDsvtpo",
   "ServerSideEncryptionMethod":null,
   "ResponseMetadata":{  
      "RequestId":"7ECD47FAC9D84AE3",
      "Metadata":{  
         "x-amz-id-2":"YAP+iltv/SfSh1p2ji6UU3Lan04usef1CV6Cy7DRcObPUa60iDd0STny9hZ6P69h"
      }
   },
   "ContentLength":234,
   "HttpStatusCode":200
}
```

According to the [API reference for the REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html), there should be a "x-amz-version-id" value in the response header that has the versionId of the new (destination) object, however.

Any suggestions on what to do other than poll the S3 service again for the versionId?  Is there some way to access the underlying response header and dig out the "x-amz-version-id" value?  Or am I just missing something?